# Laravel 5.5 global date accessor

Tags: laravel

I have a model with 4 dates, I save them and use them in french format (d/m/Y).

Here is my model :

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';

    protected $dates = [
        'date_1',
        'date_2',
        'date_3',
        'date_4',
    ];

    // ...
```

It seems to work correctly for saving them, but $dateFormat is not applied when I want to show the property. It's like it's not an accessor.

Is there a nice way to write an accessor for all $dates ?

If I write this function, it works well :

```
public function getDate1Attribute($value)
{
    return (new \DateTime($value))->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

But I would like a global way. I tried function `getAttributes()` but it's never called ?

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `$dateFormat` is the format you will **save** all **date** fields in the database, even timestamps: `created_at` and `updated_at`.

If a field is defined to be a **date** when you retrieve it you will get a `Carbon` instance, so you can do things like this one:

```
$model->date_1->format('d/m/Y');
```

You can read more here in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

AFAIK there is no way to write a global getter for date without overwriting some internal `Eloquent` functions, one thing I did was to write an helper `to_date()` that accept a `Carbon` instance and return a locale formatted string

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if you find it useful